# How to use a non-argument variable in function?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glfw

Learning opengGL(+glfw) I met interesting thing: I have to use only one kind of prototype of function `mouse_callback`in `glfwSetCursorPosCallback (Glfwwindow* ,  GLFWcursorposfun mouse_callback);` How I should I use variable `GLfloat yaw = -90.0f;` in my `mouse_callback` without passing it as argument(there will be an error) or global variables.

Comment: Since I saw callbacks in X11 the first time, there is usually always a client data pointer which is registered together with function pointer and passed to callback. This could be used to "bind" client data. Somehow it seems the GLFW people forgot this (or left this out for performance considerations). Either you store your client data in the Window (as suggested by LRiO), or you have to store them in global variables. I see no other way around.

Comment: Please post the code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. C function pointers do not support binding arguments. Generally, you can pass a pointer to a specific function that already has that value `-90.0f` baked into it, or use a global variable.

Yes, this sucks. It's why C++ introduced `std::bind`, and then lambdas. Unfortunately, the OpenGL API does not allow you to make use of such functionality.

However, it does allow you to "bind" some arbitrary data structure to a window context, via [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) and [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06), so you could explore encoding your value into that structure.

Comment: Only after reading this answer, I understand what the question asked. Maybe the downvote means "don't answer unclear questions". Only guessing.

Comment: Thanks, I did like you said with functions, looked for more "elegant" way